# Multiple input files to `awk`?

Tags: awk

I have a bunch of files named `dataX.dat` where `X` is a number that ranges over an interval. I was trying to get the seventh line of each of those and take them to a new file using `awk` but it just gets the latest one (the one with the highest `X`:

```
awk 'NR==7' data*.dat
```

only displays the seventh line of data128.dat being 128 the last one of them. Why does it do so and how should I do it so it takes all the files?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The system orders files alphabetically and 128 happens to be the first one (no other `X` number starts with `1`), so it's actually taking only the first file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NR is across all files, FNR is in each file:

```
awk 'FNR==7' data*.dat
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
for file in *
do 
   awk ... "$file"
done
```

If you need to awk on multiple files recursively, then use find command instead like `find . -type f -exec awk ... {} ;`